# Github service connection not updating with Azure Devops

Tags: github, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I have an Azure DevOps Pipeline (YAML), where the projects and templates are stored in separate repositories, both in github. I have a service connection setup to github so that my pipeline can access the repositories that the project references. That works, except it only seems to pick up the version of the repository that existed when the connection was created. Same for repositories that were created afterwords. I had to recreate the connection after adding a repository.

It doesn't seem like a 'Service Connection' should be a static snapshot of a repository, but that is how it is acting. I have errors in the pipeline due to a typo, but after fixing it, I am getting the same error with the same type.

Any idea what is going on here? I am not using the refs property to refer to a specific commit, it should be latest. I've recreated the pipeline as well, and no change.

Comment: I am confused about this `except it only seems to pick up the version of the repository that existed when the connection was created. Same for repositories that were created afterwords. I had to recreate the connection after adding a repository` . Can you add some screenshots to illustrate? I created a new repo in github, using the existing service connection will [show the new repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlxI9.png).

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hi, sorry. It actually started working after a day. So, after creating that service connection, it didn't recognize changes in the existing repositories. But, the next day, everything started working as expected. I am not sure what the issue was. I actually was not the one who created the connection in this case. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: Glad to hear this problem is solved, if this problem occurs again, you can try to grant access in Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to grant access in Github.

[image]

Or click `provide access` when creating github yaml pipeline.

[image]

[image]